# How to change the plot x axis in time series in graph objects plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I want them to go from 0 to 24 h to export those images and create a gif.
[image]

Comment: If you want an answer, you must include sample data, code by text, in your question.

Comment: i would look into [animations](https://plotly.com/python/animations/). but please rewrite your question – copy and paste the code instead of a screenshot (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors))